# How to get access to the command line of your delphi deployed datasnap server on a linux docker container

Tags: docker, delphi, console-application, paserver

I'm prototyping various deployment scenarios for my future delphi web projects. And as I'm going to build the nextgen killer app (...) , I investigated cloud deployment of a docker container for my backend API datasnap server.
As I was new to docker in general and relatively unfamiliar with linux, it was not straightforward.

But I managed to build an delphi 11 alexandria compatible PAServer image and deploy simple apps to my local docker desktop environment ( the radstudio/paserver docker hub images today are unfortunately 10.4.x only versions so no click and run possible...).

However, when deploying a default delphi datasnap webbroker server ( as console application ), the program returns to it's command line and waits for a 'start' instruction.

Sofar, I did't succeed in getting access to that program commandline interactively inside the docker CLI to enter that 'start' instruction ( or get access to the PAServer commandline to e.g. trigger a verbose session for the same matter ).
Yes, I can start the server by default and it 'fixes' the problem but sooner or later I will need this to be available  ?

I tried one ( general ) suggestion ( get-apt install reptyr / reptyr PID ) to get access to running processes but it returns with errors and since I'm really newbie on linux/Docker I have no further ideas.
( FYI Deploying to windows, simply opens a command line window that stays available to type in )

```
# reptyr 83
[-] Timed out waiting for child stop.
Unable to attach to pid 83: Operation not permitted
#
```

( and an exception is raised in the IDE session 'Project raised exception class Stopped(user)(18)', but the session can be continued )

Comment: "Get a shell in a container" is usually more of an emergency debugging tool than something you want to do routinely.  Imagine you're pushing a daily update to 1,000 copies of your container: you don't want to manually log into each of these to start the server.  In the Dockerfile set the `CMD` to start the application, and don't worry about interactive shells.

Comment: Ok, I absolutely agree that this is not something you want for production. But in this dev phase, I like to explore.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if you start the docker container in interactive mode, the docker host commandline will convert into the container commandline, attached to the 'main' process with PID 1 ( I guess ).

docker run -it -p 8082:8082 -p 64211:64211 -p 80:80 mypaserverimage

connected to the PAServer command line.
But still it remains how to connect to the commandline of the subsequent PAServer deployed console application.

( can't seem to run the container that way from the docker desktop GUI. Need to run from docker host command line )

[image]